# MongoDB FindAndModify Sorting

Tags: sorting, mongodb

I am using FindAndModify in MongoDB in several concurrent processes. The collection size is about 3 million entries and everything works like a blast as long as I don't pass a sorting option (by an indexed field). Once I try to do so, the following warning is spawned to the logs:

```
warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns: test_db.wengine_queue top: 
{ 
opid: 424210, 
active: true, 
lockType: "write", 
waitingForLock: false, 
secs_running: 0, 
op: "query", 
ns: "test_db", 
query: { 
    findAndModify: "wengine_queue", 
    query: { 
            locked: { $ne: 1 }, 
            rule_completed: { $in: [ "", "0", null ] }, 
            execute_at: { $lt: 1324381363 }, 
            company_id: 23, 
            debug: 0, 
            system_id: "AK/AK1201" 
        }, 
    update: { 
            $set: { locked: 1 } 
        }, 
    sort: { 
            execute_at: -1 
        } 
}, 
client: "127.0.0.1:60873", 
desc: "conn", 
threadId: "0x1541bb000", 
connectionId: 1147, 
numYields: 0 
}
```

I do have all the keys from the query indexed, here they are:

```
PRIMARY> db.wengine_queue.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "_id_"
},  
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "system_id" : 1,
        "company_id" : 1,
        "locked" : 1,
        "rule_completed" : 1,
        "execute_at" : -1,
        "debug" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "system_id_1_company_id_1_locked_1_rule_completed_1_execute_at_-1_debug_1"
},  
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "debug" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "debug_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "system_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "system_id_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "company_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "company_id_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "locked" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "locked_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "rule_completed" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "rule_completed_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "execute_at" : -1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "execute_at_-1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "thread_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "thread_id_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "rule_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test_db.wengine_queue",
    "name" : "rule_id_1"
}
]
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: It's just a warning that says the update cannot yield. Does anything actually stop working or are you just worried about the warning? MongoDB/10gen has a somewhat different opinion on what should and shouldn't be a logged warning so you end up with quite a few things being logged as a warning that probably shouldn't

Comment: No, everything works fine. I am worried about the warning though and the implications it mights have when my setup is taken to production (about 50mil documents)

Comment: It's relatively innocent. I'll post an answer

Comment: It's not harmless when it fills a disk with log messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested -- I had to create a separate index ending with the key that the set is to be sorted by.

Comment: MongoDB documentation says ["the sort column must be the last column used in index"](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-1.Thesortcolumnmustbethelastcolumnusedintheindex.)

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov it no longer seems to say this.

Comment: Indeed. Now it says ["For queries that include a sort that uses a compound index, ensure that all fields before the first sorted field are equality matches"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#use-indexes-to-sort-query-results)

Answer (score 1):

That warning is thrown when an operation that wants to yield (such as long updates, removes, etc.) cannot do so because it cannot release the lock it's holding for whatever reason.

Do you have the field you're sorting on indexed? If not adding an index for that will probably remove the warnings.

Comment: yes, the field is indexed as you can see from the result of "getIndexes()" above

Comment: Ah sorry. In that case you'll have to live with the warning I think. Again, it's just the result of a lengthy update that wants to yield but can't. By the way there are one or two useless indexes in there. Note that index {a:1, b:1, c:1} and {a:1} are not useful since the former includes the latter.

Comment: So you suggest I just keep the compound index? What about other operations that may use only "C" or "B" and "C"?

Comment: Yes, if you have {a:1, b:1, c:1} then {a:1} and {a:1, b:1} are implied. This is NOT the case for {b:1}, {c:1} or {b:1, c:1}. It's from left to right.